# how to get rid of "TextView" at the end of each item?

Tags: android, android-studio

[How would I get rid of "TextView" shown at the end of each item in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td7i3.jpg)
How would I get rid of "TextView" shown at the end of each item in the image??Cannot find "TextView" anywhere.I have not given "TextView" anywhere and the site from which I got the code does not it in their output.
I used codes from different website so the declarations won't look connected.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".ScreenOne">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:textSize="20sp"/>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/findSelected"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Next>" />

  <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

```
    public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_one);
     displayListView();
     checkButtonClick();
     }

     private void displayListView() {

     //Array list of countries
      ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
      Country country = new Country("PC (Laptop/desktop)",false);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Mobile phone",true);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Electricals",false);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Printer",true);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Kettle",true);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Microwave",false);
      countryList.add(country);
      country = new Country("Fridge",false);
      countryList.add(country);

      //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
      dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.country_info, countryList);
      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     // Assign adapter to ListView
      listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) dataAdapter);


      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicked on Row: " + country.getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      });
 }

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;
    public MyCustomAdapter(ScreenOne context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
        this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;
                    Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
                                    " is " + cb.isChecked(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Country country = countryList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(country.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(country);

        return convertView;
    }
}

private void checkButtonClick() {
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ScreenOne.this,ScreenTwo.class));
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: In other words, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: please share the code in your layout.xml of the screen you posted

Comment: add your listView1 code

Comment: You never set `code` to anything.

Comment: Please add your "country_info" layout too.

Answer (score 0):

before you return your convertView, add the following:

```
holder.code.setText("");
```

Suggestion: I understand you're just borrowing code from other solutions, but don't be afraid to personalise it. Instead of keeping the variable *country*, rename it to something that suits your project (eg *appliance*). If you select the variable in android studio and right click on it, select refactor->rename and give it a new name, it will change the variable's name everywhere that's used, without you having to worry about forgetting something.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was just lazy to change the variable though.